# assembly printf call printing wrong value

Tags: assembly, format, printf

At this point in my code I know that eax contains 12345678 (Says so in my debugger)

```
    push    eax
    push    print_r
    call    printf
    add     esp, 8
```

My format string is

```
print_r:    db 0Ah, "number: %hd", 10, 0
```

Instead of printing 12345678, it prints 24910

When eax contains 1234 however, it correctly prints 1234

I have a feeling it has to do with the string formating %hd, but I don't know what to do to make it so it can print reguardless of how big/ what the sign the number is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean %ld

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use `%hd` for printing. 
`%hd` takes an 16b value and print it, but you provide a 32b values.

What is happening: Your value is 12345678 which means 0xBC614E. Now because you use `%hd`, `printf` will only consider 16b form this number (number will be truncated to 16b) and the value printed will be 0x614e which is exactly your printed value: 24910.

2 possible fixed:

- Replace into printf format "%hd" with "%d"
- Use for printing number on 16b (between -32769 and 32768).